# Jquery to fix scroll down to bottom - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a setInterval() to load one part of the page for every 1 second. Everything is working fine but, I am displaying all the messages using a table. I want scroll bar always to the bottom.we have to scroll down to view new messages. So, I want my scroll bar fix to the bottom by default.

Jquery code which is loading the messages table

```
setInterval(function(){
        if(user.trim()!=""){
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "getuserconversation",
                data: {username: user},
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(data){                
                    if(data.success){
                        $(".messages").load("conversation_of_users.jsp");
                        var $mydiv = $("#msgs");
                         $mydiv.scrollTop($mydiv.height());
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("error");
                }   
            });

        }       
    }, 5000);
```

It was working but, there is a problem. It goes to bottom of the table and within 1 second it is returning to top again. I saw this while debugging. In real time we cant even see that. I dont know why it is going to top again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is returning to top but you can solve your problem using `return false;` at end of the callback.
or you can use  `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I have used return false & event prevent. But, it didn't work.